# How to add logo to Materialize SideNav with HTML

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using a Materialize SideNav and want to add a logo to it similar to how they have it on their website:

[image]

However, it's not coming out right when I try to do it:

[image]

Here's the code I'm using to try to add it:

```
<ul id="side-nav" class="side-nav fixed">
  <li><a href="#"><img class="responsive-img" src="img/m.png"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Featured</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Workouts</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Movements</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to do this the **simplest** way possible. Is there a way to properly format it with pure HTML? Or am I going to have to do some CSS formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add one more `ul` tag to `img`:

```
<ul id="side-nav" class="side-nav fixed">
```

> ```
> <ul><li><a href="#"><img class="responsive-img" src="img/m.png"></a></li></ul>
> ```

```
  <li><a href="#">Featured</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Workouts</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Movements</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
</ul>
```

Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/etamity/f8vv1h10/1/

Comment: I edited the answer, please check http://jsfiddle.net/etamity/f8vv1h10/1/

Comment: would you mind share your code with jsfiddle? Then it will be easier to debug.

Comment: can't seem to get a linked image to stay, so try and replace that image with any linked image in the jsfiddle